# On Img Hover show text in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to do this:

I've a images with a text inside figure

```
<figure>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <caption><span class="text">TEXT</span></caption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="" alt="">
    <caption><span class="text">TEXT 2</span></caption>
</figure>


<div id="showhere"></div>
```

I need when I hover an image to display its text inside another div; `<div id="showhere"></div>` and when mouse is out to hide the text.

I've tried it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/dH9yb/) but I'm not very good with jQuery, just starting to learn it.. Can somebody help me out?

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dH9yb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$("figure").hover(function() {
   var data=$(this).find(".text").html();
    $("#showhere").hide().stop().html(data).fadeIn();

}, function() {
    $("#showhere").fadeOut();
});
```

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dH9yb/1/)

Comment: Wow thank you! I would have never thought of doing it like that, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$("img").hover(function(){  //Cursor in handler
    $('#showhere').text(
        $(this).next('caption').find('.text').text()
    );
}, function(){              //Cursor out handler
    $('#showhere').text('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$("figure").hover(function() {
    $("#showhere").text($(this).find(".text").text());
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".text").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").hover(
       function () {
      $("#showhere").html( $(this).attr("alt") );
       }, 
       function () {
          ("#showhere").html("");
       }
    );
 });
```

You get much cleaner code by using the `alt` attribute:
http://jsfiddle.net/dH9yb/